# How to find Model where this field or that field is in a list of acceptable values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I find the relationships where the start node or the end node is in the list.

```
ids = ProcessingRun.last.nodes.pluck(:id)
@rels = Relationship.where(:end_node_id => ids) + Relationship.where(:start_node_id => ids)
```

I've tried lots of variations on OR

```
rels_in_id_array = Relationship.where("start_node_id in #{ids} OR end_node_id in#{ids}")
```

Relationship Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE (start_node_id in [35752, 35726, 35728, 35729, 35731, 35735, 35736, 35738, 35742, 35745, 35750, 35751, 35723, 35725, 35739, 35740, 35749, 35724, 35722, 35733, 35734, 35737, 35741, 35743, 35732, 35746, 35747, 35721, 35730, 35727, 35744, 35748, 35753] OR end_node_id in[35752, 35726, 35728, 35729, 35731, 35735, 35736, 35738, 35742, 35745, 35750, 35751, 35723, 35725, 35739, 35740, 35749, 35724, 35722, 35733, 35734, 35737, 35741, 35743, 35732, 35746, 35747, 35721, 35730, 35727, 35744, 35748, 35753])
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE (start_node_id in [35752, 35...

and it's not working....

so that's why I thought I'd add 2 arrays together.  But it turns out they are arrays, not ActiveRecord relations, so I can't do things with them that you can do with AR relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Relationship.where("start_node_id IN (?) OR end_node_id IN (?)", ids, ids)
```

Comment: You can also use symbols and a hash for interpolation, which is useful where you have repeated vars: `.where("start_node_id IN (:ids) OR end_node_id IN (:ids)", ids: ids)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Relationship.where('end_node_id IN (?) OR start_node_id IN (?)', ids, ids)
```